# How can I format date using json.SerializerSettings.Converters to look like 1288323623006

Tags: c#, json

I am currently using the following date filter in my WebAPI application:

```
json.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add( 
   new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm" });
```

I started to use this as my front end could not understand the dates. If I remember correctly it was due to the way milliseconds were formatted with too many digits.

What I need is to get the date into a format like this:

```
1288323623006
```

Can someone suggest how I can do this using the serializer. Is this different from the default?

Comment: What date/time is 1288323623006 meant to be?

Comment: {{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}: Oct 29, 2010 11:40:23 AM

Comment: Are you after the `unix timestamp` by chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `IsoDateTimeConverter` at all - you *possibly* want to use [`JavaScriptDateTimeConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_JavaScriptDateTimeConverter.htm). That will convert it into `new Date(...)` with the right value - but I believe it really will include the `new Date(...)` part. If you don't want that, you'll probably need to write your own converter.

It shouldn't be too hard to write a converter - although you need to decide how to handle the different kinds of `DateTime`. For example, if you're asked to convert a `DateTime` with a `Kind` of `Unspecified`, do you want to assume it's actually already in UTC, or already in the system local time zone, or something else?

Once you've got an appropriate "instant" in time, you just need to find the number of milliseconds between that and the Unix epoch (1st January 1970 00:00:00, UTC) and convert that number of milliseconds into a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you want

```
 private static readonly long DatetimeMinTimeTicks = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,     DateTimeKind.Utc)).Ticks;
 long b = (long)((Calendar1.SelectedDate).ToUniversalTime().Ticks - DatetimeMinTimeTicks) / 10000;
```